# Application execution monitoring for Spark job on yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I can see the application execution information in detail on the Web UI in Spark  standalone mode, but when comes to yarn, it is gone. So, where can I see the execution information when job is ran on yarn?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure spark history server with yarn ,and then start it

in your `spark-defaults.conf` file add the following properties,

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://LOCATION/TO/SPARK/EVENT/LOG

spark.yarn.historyServer.address        SPARK_HISTORY_SERVER_HOST
spark.history.ui.port                   SPARK_HISTORY_SERVER_PORT

spark.yarn.services                     org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryService
spark.history.fs.logDirectory           hdfs://LOCATION/TO/SPARK/EVENT/LOG
```

and then start spark history server:

`$/PATH/TO/SPARK/sbin/start-history-server.sh`

P.S. I assume that Spark is already configured with hadoop/yarn (so you have set the location of configuration files in spark-env.sh)

Answer (score 0):

You can [debug your application](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#debugging-your-application) , but I guess there is no UI dedicated for that.

Comment: You may also reconstruct the UI of a finished application through Spark’s history server
 http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact

Comment: Yes, execution history can be shown in that way, I'm trying to figure this problem.